# VBA code to find a cell contains a certain string (among a .csv list)

Tags: excel, vba

Found plenty of example to find a cell based on the value it contains but they are all for the example when the cell contains ONLY one value. I have this columns with a list of locales like deDE, esES, etc. and if I try to find a cell based on just one of those locale, the code I have doesn't work, I have no idea why.

```
Sub Test()


Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range

    strConcatList = "*" & "esES" & "*"

    'For each used cell in Column A of sheet1, check whether the value in that cell
    'is contained within the concatenated string
    For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Requests").Range("G:G"), Sheets("Requests").UsedRange)
        If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then       'InStr returns 0 if the string isn't found
        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add.Name = "esES"

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Requests").Select
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

For instance, this code snippet is supposed to find cells where "esES" is present, create a new sheet called esES and paste the row in it. I tried "esES", didn't work. I was hoping the current form I have would work - I have a little bit of experience with Regax albeit not in VBA and it should read anything + esES + anything.

No clue what's going on, and I've been stuck for hours. I wouldn't mind a little help here.

EDIT:

This code is working, thanks for helping:

```
Sub Test()


Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range

    Sheets.Add.Name = "esES"
    strConcatList = "*esES*"

    'For each used cell in Column G of sheet1, check whether the value in that cell
    'is contained within the concatenated string
    For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Requests").Range("G:G"), Sheets("Requests").UsedRange)
        If cell.Value Like strConcatList Then
        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("esES").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Requests").Select
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need wildcards with instr, you need Like for wildcards  instr( "Nath" , string) or string like ' * Nath * '  (without spaces, kept becoming italic)

Comment: The comment in the code mentions column **A**, but the code examines only column **G**.

Comment: replace `If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then` with `If cell.Value like strConcatList Then `

Comment: Thanks, that worked:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working:

```
Sub Test()


Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range

    Sheets.Add.Name = "esES"
    strConcatList = "*esES*"


    For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Requests").Range("G:G"), Sheets("Requests").UsedRange)
        If cell.Value Like strConcatList Then
        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("esES").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Requests").Select
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for helping!